# Get a value between min and max values in Python

Tags: python, return, max, min

I wan't to get a value if it's between min and max values. If the value is smaller than min, I want to get the min value and if it's greater than max I want to get the max.
I use this code  now, but is there an inbuilt or smarter way to do it?

```
def inBetween(minv, val, maxv):
  if minv < val < maxv: return val
  if minv > val:        return minv
  if maxv < val:        return maxv

print inBetween(2,5,10)
```

Answer (score 14):

Using [`min`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min), [`max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
>>> def inbetween(minv, val, maxv):
...     return min(maxv, max(minv, val))
... 
>>> inbetween(2, 5, 10)
5
>>> inbetween(2, 1, 10)
2
>>> inbetween(2, 11, 10)
10
```

Comment: Or in the other way around: `max(minv, min(maxv, val))`

Answer (score 7):

For the record: This kind of function is usually called `clamp` (as in *clamping*), sometimes `clip`. The signature you mostly find for this is `clamp(val, minv, maxv)`. If you don't like the idiomatic solution using the functions `min` and `max` because of the function overhead, you may use this solution:

```
def clamp(val, minv, maxv):
    return minv if val < minv else maxv if val > maxv else val
```

A quick'n'dirty performance check:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit("clamp(1, 5, 10)", "def clamp(val, minv, maxv): return min(maxv, max(minv, val))")
1.8955198710000332
>>> timeit.timeit("clamp(1, 5, 10)", "def clamp(val, minv, maxv): return minv if val < minv else maxv if val > maxv else val")
0.5956520039999305
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them in a list, sort the list, chose middle element.

```
>>> def inbetween(minv,val,maxv):
...     return sorted([minv,val,maxv])[1]
... 
>>> inbetween(2,5,10)
5
>>> inbetween(2,1,10)
2
>>> inbetween(2,11,10)
10
```